# I tried to make a new command (addrole) and everything works perfectly fine. However

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to make a new command (addRole) and everything works perfectly fine. However, I want to add something but it seems like I'm doing something wrong. So, I'm trying to make the bot check whether the member has the role/not. But the code below doesn't seem to work for me.

```
if (message.guild.members.cache.has(r => r.name)) 
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])
      .setTitle("Error")
      .setDescription(`${user.username} has that role already.`);

   return message.channel.send(embed);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.some()` instead of `.has()`

```js
message.guild.members.cache.some(r => r.name)
```